# How to assert that associative array has exactly the following scheme?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

How to efficiently check in one line that associative array has the certain keys (and that's the only ones)?

Something like

```
function validate(array $data): bool
{
    return
        count(array_intersect_key(
            $data,
            ['key_1' => true, 'key_2' => true, 'key_3' => true]
        )) === 3
        && count($data) === 3;
}
```

Comment: Why in one line? Such attempts to compact code typically lead to reduced readability and do not enhance performance.

Comment: Take keys with `array_keys` and compare arrays

Comment: I want to use it for more complex validation. But actually you are right! :)

Comment: @GrigoriiSokolik That is not a very valid reason. You can compose your validation from multiple functions. This way your code will stay clean. And even if you want to use it for a more complex validation, what stops you from splitting the logic into multiple lines of code?

Comment: What is wrong with current approach?

Comment: @sectus, I feel, that's not elegant.